# Transition Origins

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a pretty simplistic login page. I would like that the transition between `.form input[type="text"]:focus, .form input[type="password]`, instead of gradually fading the color in, it swooshes the new color from left to right.

Here is my code:

```css
.form input[type="text"],
.form input[type="password"] {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 2.5vh;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  transition-property: border-bottom-color;
  transition-duration: 350ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.form input[type="text"]:focus,
.form input[type="password"]:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #66bb6a;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="example@example.com">
</form>
```

Here is a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/juja15ro/

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you can create a https://plnkr.co/ or https://codepen.io/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ of your code, that helps the reviewers answer quicker.

Comment: What you want is that when you focus on the input, the green line, instead of showing up progressively, it starts on the left and grows to the right. Correct?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yes, that is what I am aiming for.

Comment: should the black line still be there?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro What I was aiming for was the line would be in the same position, but the green color would come from the left side and fill up the line until it reaches the right side. The line would then be green.

Comment: Is there any other element (like a div containing each input)? This is something that I feel could be easily achievable playing with the pseudo-elements, but a bit tricky with only an input (because as far as i know, you cannot play with the position of the border).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yes. I made a JSfiddle with the full code for the form:
https://jsfiddle.net/kmatv5wt/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it but with javascript.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-container input');
inputs.forEach((input) => {
 input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
   input.parentElement.classList.add('focused');
  })
  input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
   input.parentElement.classList.remove('focused');
  })
})
```

```css
.input-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: .24s ease-out;
}

.input-container input {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
}

.input-container.focused:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `span(input bar)` and added `:before` and  `:after` property to it and for the left to right movement, `before` should be `0%` and `afte`r should be `100%` .(Also try `before` to `50%` and `after` to `50%` and see movement effect starting from center) Here's my code

```css
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  background: none;
}

.inputBar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 290px;
}

.inputBar:before,
.inputBar:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: #66bb6a;
  height: 2px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.inputBar:after {
  right: 100%;
}

.inputBar:before {
  left: 0%;
}

input:focus~.inputBar:before,
input:focus~.inputBar:after {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="example@example.com">
  <span class="inputBar"></span>
</form>
```